# Android: Unable to Get All SysEx Messages from MIDI File

Tags: android, midi

I am using a [great MIDI library](https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib) to parse MIDI files.

In one of my MIDI files. I have an exclusive track consisting only of SysEx messages (~3000 messages). However, whenever the library parses the MIDI file, it recognises only 43 of all the SysEx messages. The data contained in the SysEx messages is also not fetched correctly.

Following is some sample code that I have tried (I have the MIDI file inside the `raw` folder).

```
    try {

        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stairwaysysex);
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".mid");
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        IOUtils.copy(is, out);
        MidiFile midi = new MidiFile(tempFile);
        ArrayList<MidiTrack> tracks = midi.getTracks();
        MidiTrack sysExTrack = tracks.get(tracks.size() - 1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The `sysExTrack` variable contains the incompletely parsed SysEx data.

It is also worth noting that all the other tracks are getting parsed correctly.

Comment: The parsing code looks OK. You have to provide an example.

Comment: Sure thing, any way I can share the output and the sample MIDI file directly with you?

Comment: Upload it somewhere.